# Why does the Republic use armor that is so similar to Mandalorian armor?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, attack-of-the-clones

I was looking at some images of clone armor.

[image: I was looking at some images of clone armor.]

And I noticed a remarkable resemblance to Mandalorian armor.

[image]

And to the Old Republic's troopers' armor

[image]

Especially in the Helmet, Legs, Groin, And Shoulder areas.

**Why did the Republic use Mandalorian style armor for their army?**

Canon and Non-Canon answers accepted.

Comment: To me, they look about as different as they could possibly be, given that they're both full-body armour for humanoids.

Comment: Have you noticed how similar all full-body armour is? http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/03/17/article-2116265-12353E31000005DC-952_468x468.jpg

Comment: You are the Mandalorian, you should know :D lol

Comment: I really want to write an answer so I can put a Cannon in it.

Comment: @CHEESE I very clearly stated that both Cannon and non cannon answers were accepted

Comment: @TheMandolorian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_(fiction)

Comment: @CHEESE HaHa Very funny

Comment: I'm not sure if I could write a good answer, but a lot more than the armor is based on Mandolorian culture. They are all technically Mandolorian by blood, and they embrace this culture. It's not uncommon for a clone to speak Mando'a and to give each other Mandolorian names for clones ear only. They also sometimes perform a Mandolorian warrior dance, similar to the New Zealand Haka. The training of all clones was also overseen by other Mandolorians, so this encouraged the culture. IMO the armor is modelled after Jango's as well, however, this is never stated.  OYA NER VOD!

Comment: But why would the republic model the armor for their soldiers after a Bounty Hunter

Comment: @TheMandolorian It probably wasn't the republic that picked the design as they were not aware of the army until millions of soldiers were already outfitted with the armor. It would have been the Kaminoans and whoever they involved in the process, maybe Sifo-Dyas, Jango, or the other Mandolorian trainers had some influence on the decision. Also what's with the downvote people?

Comment: I've edited the question to show that the Old Republic used the same style of armor as Clone Troopers

Comment: You should watch the movie *Attack of the Clones* again if you haven't recently, it was pretty obvious the clonetrooper armor was meant to be a modified version of Jango's armor.

Comment: Things you don’t expect to see next to a Startrooper #734: the words “Killer Cupcake”.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because the clone army consists of clones of Jango Fett, and Jango Fett was Mandalorian and he was used to use Mandalorian armor

[Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_trooper/Legends) says:

> His [Fett's] influence over the clone army's development extended into several areas, such as the resemblance between his Mandalorian armor and the their Phase I armor and the training that molded the clones into elite soldiers.

Comment: fwiw - strictly canonically speaking, Fett wasn't Mandalorian. Only his armour.

Answer (score 6):

It was partially because of Fett, but also because of heavy mandalorian influence. Many mandalorian instructors were used to train the grand army. As for the old Republic, mandalorian armour was very advanced since they conquered civilizations and stole their technology. It was therefore simple for the Republic to copy the already proven to be effective designs.

Answer (score -1):

My guess about old republic trooper armor is that after the Mandalorian wars,the Republic saw how they almost got destroyed by dudes wearing head to toe armor and figured out the benefits of it on the battlefield...

Comment: This isn’t really a proper answer as it stands - it needs some sort of evidence supporting its claim.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn’t say it’s a matter of the Old Republic idolizing the Mandalorians, but a matter of logic and practicality. (Or it just seems that way to me.) During the Mandalorian War-no armor/nearly got beat. Jedi Civil War-Sith Troopers wearing armor/nearly got beat. After those conflicts; wearing head to toe armor then looking like they are giving Sith a run for their money during fights(ex. Jace Malcolm)

Answer (score -3):

The clones' armor was based off Fett's armor, and the Old Republic was created by some guy who liked the clone armor and the Mandalorian armor. The period of time the Old Republic made this armor was RIGHT after the Mandalorian War. (Why would you idolize the one group of people who defeated you hundreds of years until the Jedi stepped in, and copy their armor?)

Comment: Do you have any sources for the second sentence? Also, the first point has been addressed in existing answers.